# Can't run any yarn/yarn uprade/yarn add without error

Tags: node.js, linux, yarnpkg

This is the second time that i encounter this problem but this time can't find a working solution.

PROBLEM: `yarn`/`yarn install`/`yarn add` do not work without error, although after running yarn and creating my node_modules I can type `yarn start` and my project works, and I can also run `yarn add examplePackage` and it gets added into node_modules successfuly.

```
    [4/4] Rebuilding all packages...
[-/6] ⢀ waiting...
[2/6] ⢀ grpc
[3/6] ⢀ node-sass
[-/6] ⢀ waiting...
error /home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/grpc: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/grpc
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.13.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@14.17.5 | linux | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.3/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.3/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.3/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.20.3 and node@14.17.5 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.3/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.17.5 | linux | x64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.17.5 | linux | x64
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:390:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.13.13-1-MANJARO
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v14.17.5-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v14.17.5-linux-x64/bin/node /home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.13.13-1-MANJARO
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v14.17.5-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.5
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v14.17.5-linux-x64/bin/node /home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/lessnet/Dokumenty/Programowanie/Inne/crwn-clth/node_modules/grpc/src/n
```

I am currently running Manjaro Pahvo with current Node LTS.

I have tried:

- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `yarn clean cache`
- Reinstalling the whole repo
- Reinstalling yarn
- Installing python2 as node-gyp or node-pre-gyp requires it

Comment: Could you try running `yarn install --force`, which is an equivalent of `npm rebuild`?
May be you can share your package.json dependencies. So people can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is wrong with grpc package. Take a look at this issue in Github raised for `grpc`:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1181

Issue Suggests the use of `@grpc/grpc-js` instead of `grpc` since `grpc` has been deprecated.